# Check $_POST array have empty values

Tags: php

I want to check `$_POST` array have empty values after form is submitted. If there are no any empty values then I need to go to the next level. If not script execute should stop.

I tried it something like this:

```
$required = [ 'company_name'
            , 'reg_number'
            , 'telephone'
            , 'mobile'
            , 'fax'
           ]; 
$proceed = false;
foreach ($required as $key) { 
    if (!empty($_POST[$key])){ 
        $proceed = true; 
        break; 
    } 
}

if($proceed) {
 // next level 
}
```

But my problem is, if there are empty values in post array the script is going to next level.

can anybody tell me what is the reason for this? 
Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Filter out all empty values with `array_filter()` and compare the amount of elements left with the amount of elements in the array

Comment: Well obviously your logic is reversed. Once you reach a filled value you do stop checking. E.g. if the first value IS NOT empty, you will not check the others.

Comment: @Rizier123, can you show me an example with `array_filter()`. Thank you.

Comment: `array_filter($_POST, function($e) { // filter $e on some condition });`

Comment: @user3733831. Simply change: 1) `$proceed = false;` (second statement) to `$proceed = true;`. 2) `if (!empty($_POST[$key])){ $proceed = true;` to `if (empty($_POST[$key])){ $proceed = false;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you consider the presence of any of your required values as being good enough to proceed. You need to flip this around: assume there are no missing values, then loop through to check if any required values are missing. If any one of them are missing, update your missing values check then continue.

If you want to make the smallest modification to your existing code, you want something like this:

```
$required = [ 'company_name'
            , 'reg_number'
            , 'telephone'
            , 'mobile'
            , 'fax'
           ];

$missingValues = false;

foreach ($required as $key) {
    if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $missingValues = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$missingValues) {
    // next level
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$proceed = !in_array("", $required);
```